# How to give user access to specific folder in home directory

Tags: permissions, users, group

I'm trying to set up a 'deploy' user on my VPS (running CentOS 6 and cPanel) which needs to have access to a specific folder from another home directory: `/home/nazeem/public_html/staging`.

I've created the *deploy* user succesfully, but logically it didn't have access to the specific home folder of user *nazeem*. After some reading I discovered that I need to put both users in a group and give the staging folder group permissions.

I've added both users to the group `deploy`, as is displayed in the `/etc/group` file:

```
deploy:x:32012:nazeem,deploy
```

I also changed the ownership of the folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 deploy deploy 4096 feb 21 20:07 staging/
```

However, when I `cd` to the folder as user *deploy*, I still get the following:

```
-bash: cd: /home/nazeem/public_html/staging: Permission denied
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also ensure that you have the right to access (go through) the `/home/nazeem/public_html` and `/home/nazeem` folders. You can achieve this by doing a `chgrp` to group *deploy* on both folders, and setting the execution rights for the group on these folders (execution permission on a directory gives the right to go through it).

```
chgrp deploy /home/nazeem/public_html /home/nazeem
chmod g+x /home/nazeem/public_html /home/nazeem
```